# Autocovariance function at lag k for the process $x_t=A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$

Tags: time-series

> Let {$x_t$} be the process given by  $x_t$=$A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$ where
>   $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated random variables with mean $0$ and
>   variance $1$ and $w$ is a fixed frequency in the interval $[0, \pi]$.
>   Find its autocovariance function at lag $k$, where $k=0,1,2,...$

I did:

$$\gamma{(k)}=E(x_tx_{t-k})=E[(A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt))(A\cos(w(t-k))+B\sin(w(t-k)))]$$

Is there a way to make this easier to compute?

Comment: Simply apply the formula for the covariance of linear combinations: that is, covariance is a *bilinear* function of the coefficients.

Comment: I found the duplicate with [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sin+cos+auto*), which may have other helpful links.